# How to send parameter POST method in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

On my site I have combobox in php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUserVisits(reservationObjectId)
{
    //alert(reservationObjectId);
    if (reservationObjectId == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_user.php?q=" +reservationObjectId,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}       
</script>
```

```
<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUserVisits(this.value)">
    <!-- <option value="">Select a person:</option> -->
    <option value="1">aaa1</option>
    <option value="2">aaa2</option>
    <option value="3">aaa3</option>
    <option value="4">aaa4</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

When user change item in combobox, method showUserVisits is called by ajax. And I must pass reservationObjectId to get_user.php site. How it is done GET method, by I want to pass this parameter by POST method because in GET method someone can change id. How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: dont be fooled, also post items can be edited, just as simple as get items. Just make sure you always check your data.

Comment: @John Do you mean if request be send by `post` method params will be shown in url ?

Comment: @DaHaKa: Not in the URL, but POST parameters can easily be modified using a browser extension

Comment: @xbonez Such as firebug or with other extensions ?

Comment: Yeah, I think firebug does that. You can hijack any outgoing AJAX request, make changes to it and then send it.

Comment: @DahaKa Via POST the parameters don't show in the URL, but using Firebug or TamperData the user can change the parameter. With Firebug the user can change HTML code to whatever he wants too.

Comment: It does not matter, just never ever trust user data from GET, POST and COOKIE. They can all be changed easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_user.php?q=" +reservationObjectId,true);
```

To this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", url,true);
```

See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757849(v=vs.85).aspx

Here are some examples:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

One of the examples (from above link):

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: Is it sent as a POST value this way? It looks like is it sent as a GET value, but s is also sent via POST this way?

Answer (score 2):

You add the key-val pairs in `.send()`, like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","get_user.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("reservationId=" + reservationObjectId);
```

To add multiple key-value pairs, use `&` as the delimiter.

In your server side script, you'll be able to access it in `$_POST['reservationID']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp.open( "POST", 'get_user.php', true );
xmlhttp.send( "q="+reservationObjectId );
```

But keep in mind post data can be edited also, so in your php file, check the value!

```
$q = (int) $_POST['q'];
```

And make sure that reservationID belongs to the user

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work, it send nothing, I have to add http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); and now parameter is sent

Comment: @Robert you only need to set the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Below code shows how to do a post, but with POST method someone can also change the id

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","get_user.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("q="+encodeURIComponent(reservationObjectId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUserVisits(reservationObjectId)
{
//alert(reservationObjectId);
if (reservationObjectId == "")
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");          // set header in case of post method
xmlhttp.open("POST","get_user.php",true); // set post method
xmlhttp.send("q="+reservationObjectId); // set data
```

}